# Control Panel Missing Items

Tags: control-panel

I just installed a copy of Craft 4.6.0 on a new server. Everything went fine, but when I go to the CP the only options are Dashboard, Utilities and Plugin Store - no Entries, Settings, etc.

The site is in dev mode (shows at the bottom of main menu) and I am definitely the admin. Hoping someone could point me in the right direction[image]

Comment: Do you have `allowAdminChanges` set to `false` in `config/general.php`?

Comment: I do now - thanks Brad!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brad - the issue was allowAdminChanges = false in config/general. Note that was set as the default when downloading Craft 4.zip